# DevC++: How I program iterating over all elements from an STL collection properly?

Tags: dev-c++

I'm currently studying about loops and I found this found and I programmed it on DevC++ and here's my code.

#include < iostream >

#include < vector >

using namespace std;

int main()

{

std::vector < std::string > names = {"Albert Einstein", "Stephen Hawking", "Michael Ellis"}; for(std::vector< std::string >::iterator it = names.begin(); it != names.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}

}

after compiling it I had problem and here's what the compiler said:

C:\Users\chesc\Pictures\image\loops.cpp In function 'int main()':
9   89

C:\Users\chesc\Pictures\image\loops.cpp [Error] in C++98 'names' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'

9   89  C:\Users\chesc\Pictures\image\loops.cpp [Error] could not convert '{"Albert Einstein", "Stephen Hawking", "Michael Ellis"}' from '' to 'std::vector >'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please format your question better. Put code into code sample.

To answer you. Your compiler is set to standard C++98. This standard does not allow the way of initialisation you used.

I suggest you to set your compiler for the newest standard it can support. It means C++11 and higher.

You can do it in Project Options -> Compiler -> Code Generation -> Language standards

Comment: If it help, could you please mark the answer to close the question?